# How to do heterogeneous volume absorption using path tracing?

Tags: pathtracing, volumetric

I want to do volume rendering using path tracing with a **absorption only** model. And my data is in a 3D grid, which is turned into a voxel medium in my renderer.

However, I can't seem to be correct implementing the algorithm.

According to [this note](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6630/2012sp/notes/09volpath.pdf) (however absorption-only heterogeneous case is not mentioned here), the radiance at point $x$, direction $\omega$, with **emission-absorption** model in a **homogeneous** medium is:

$L(x,\omega) = \int_{x}^{y} \tau(x,x') \epsilon(x')dx + \tau(x,y)L_e(x,\omega)$

where $\tau$ is the attenuation, y is a point on surface, and $\epsilon$ is emission at point $x'$.

So I come up with the **heterogenous**, **absorption-only** equation as:

$L(x, \omega) = \tau(x,y)L_e(x,\omega)$

since I think the emission term should be omitted. However this equation seems not correct intuitively and do not give correct image.

According to this equation, the radiance at every point $x'$ along the ray within the volume is not counted, which is where I think the problem lies.

So **what is the correct heterogeneous volume path tracing equation?**
**How to derive the correct equation?**

I give more details of my implementation here. The scene is simply a **cornell box** where only a voxel medium is inside the box. I trace a ray from the eye(camera), and the ray go through the medium and intersect a surface(the wall). To simplify the procedure, I set `max_bounce` to **1** which means the path is 
`eye -> medium -> surface -> light`.

So the value of this sample is simply the *throughput of the medium* times *the throughput of the surface* times *direct light at surface intersection*.

[image]

However I got the result image

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation for the absorption-only model is correct: You multiply the luminance $L_x$ at the surface by the transmittance of the participating media between eye and the surface. For homogeneous media you can calculate this analytically using [Beer-Lambert law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer%E2%80%93Lambert_law):
$$L_y=L_xe^{-\mu|x-y|}$$
For heterogeneous medium you can calculate the transmittance by ray march through the medium using for example Woodcock tracking explained in [the paper you referred](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6630/2012sp/notes/09volpath.pdf).